# How to get username after basic authentication in javascript

Tags: javascript, glassfish, basic-authentication, jdbcrealm

I have a javascript application (.war) deployed on Glassfish server.

In my web.xml I define the following :

```
     <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
     </login-config>
```

in order to perform user authentication due to the "jdbc-realm" predefined and configured on the glassfish server.

How could I retreive username after logging in (through browser's basic login form)?